# homogenous network

Tags: networking

I'm a network geek learning Swift and containers wanting to share code. I have the T-Mobile network tower with 2 ports and a FEW APPLE air ports. A Le Potato (Arabian), A Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu) and a MAC M1 mini.

Since3 Swift PLAYGROUNDS and XCODE will run one on the mini, I can create, learn and compile there but run them on all.

My GOAL is to link all three across the network to allow file share. Unfortunately I can't get that running. Please point me to some articles that will allow me to do so.

Comment: It sounds like this has more to do with network configuration than Ubuntu itself?